# Flutter Android - Camera Out of Memory

Tags: android, flutter

I am getting OOM Exceptions when taking multiple pictures on Android. I am using the [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) plugin from pub.dev.

The problem occurs only if I take high resolution pictures and only after I took some. I have a hard time remembering reading that this error occurs when the camera (Intent) is called. This would probably be somewhere in the implementation?

Nevertheless I cannot reduce the image resolution because my app relies on the high quality of the images.

Does anyone know about this "problem" and have a solution for it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunetely image_picker is a massive memory hog - It needs >4GB to work consistently.  I'm testing on a 3GB device and it'll OOM pretty much 100% of the time.

You can implement the camera directly using fluter example code.. disadvantage is you have to supply your own UI and the images don't go into the photo gallery.. so it's only a partial solution.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Unfortunately my app relies on the UI controls of the camera app and implementing my own UI would not bring the desired output.

Comment: I suspect you're hosed then, since there isn't a good implementation of the camera I've found in flutter beyond image_picker.

There was one called camera_camera but it's out of date so won't link with any recent flutter programs.